# Matlab: plotting animation with fixed axes

Tags: matlab, plot

When I call this function, the axes are moving with the plot. How can I stop this from happening? I tried putting `xlim` and `ylim` before the function in the command window but that didn't work.

My code is:

```
function h = plootwithanimation(x,y) 

    for  h = 1:length(x)
        plot(x(h),y(h),'*')
        pause(1)
        hold on
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [fixing the bounds](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) using the `axis` function:

```
function h = plootwithanimation(x,y) 


for  h = 1:length(x)
     plot(x(h),y(h),'*')
     axis([0 10 -2 100]) %or whatever you want. This sets 0<x<10 and -2<y<100
     pause(1)
     hold on

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the bounds by using [`xlim`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) and [`ylim`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) as you tried, but plotting will ignore whatever you set the axes to before calling `plot`.

You should instead use them after the plot

```
function h = plotwithanimation(x, y, xlims, ylims) 
% Also pass in axis limits 
%   xlims = [x0,x1] 
%   ylims = [y0,y1]

hold on; % You only have to hold on once around plotting
for  h = 1:length(x)
    plot(x(h),y(h),'*');
    xlim(xlims);
    ylim(ylims);
    pause(1);
end
hold off; % Good habit so you don't accidentally plot over this figure later
```